# How to queue up a job

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to queue up a job that depends on a running job's output, so the new job waits until the running job terminates?

Hypothetical example: You should have run:

```
./configure && make
```

but you only ran:

```
./configure
```

and now you want to tell make to get on with it once configure (successfully) finishes, while you go do something useful like have a nap? The same scenario occurs with many other time-consuming jobs.

(The basic job control commands -- fg, bg, jobs, kill, &, ctrl-Z -- don't do this, as far as I know. The question arose on bash/Ubuntu, but I'd be interested in a general *nix solution, if it exists.)

Comment: don't quite get it. in `./configure && make`, `make` runs only after `./configure` succeeds. in the mean time, i think you can go take a cup of coffee. but if there are errors, for sure it cannot fix itself. if you want to judge the next mission of the screen output, i think the best choice is scripting.

Comment: Type the `make` command blindly (and hit Enter) in the output of the `configure`, the terminal buffer will hold it until the tty is ready.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume you're typing these commands at a shell prompt, and the `./configure` command is still running.

```
./configure
# oops, forgot type type "make"
[ $? -eq 0 ] && make
```

The command `[ $? -eq 0 ]` will succeed if and only if the `./configure` command succeeds.

(You could also use `[ $? = 0 ]`, which does a string comparison rather than a numeric comparison.)

(If you're willing to assume that the `./configure` command will succeed, you can just type `make`.)

Stealing and updating an idea from chepner's comment, another possibility is to suspend the job  by typing <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>, then put it in the background (`bg`), then:

```
wait %% && make
```

`wait %%` waits for "current" job, which is "the last job stopped while it was in the foreground or started in the background". This can be generalized to wait for any job by replacing `%%` by a different job specification.

You can simplify this to

```
wait && make
```

if you're sure you have no other background jobs (`wait` with no arguments waits for all background jobs to finish).

Comment: Or, if it still running, suspend it, put it in the background with `bg`, then use the easer-to-type `wait && make`.

Comment: @chepner: `wait` with no arguments waits for *all* background processes. `wait %% && make` should work.

Comment: Both your answers are excellent, @KeithThompson. The first is intuitive, and the second is a great general case to refer to the current bg job. In fact, `wait %n && make` will specify job number n.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the previous process return code with `$?`:

```
test $? -eq 0 && make
```

Comment: Did you try that? I get `0: command not found`. See my answer.

Comment: I fixed it using `test`!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your needs, but I often use [batch(1)](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_batch.htm) (from package `atd` on Debian) to compile, in a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) like this:

```
batch << EOJ
  make > _make.log 2>&1
EOJ
```

<sup>Of course it makes only sense if your `configure` did run successfully and completely</sup>

Then in some terminal I might follow the compilation with `tail -f _make.log` (provided I am in the good directory). You can get a coffee -or a lunch, or sleep a whole night- (and even logout) during the compilation.